# Is there a generic data container for Android?

Tags: android

I am coming from a `C#` world, and used `DataTable` class extensively.

Is there a similar structure to .Net `DataTable` in Android SDK?

Note that I need a structure which would hold metadata and actual records
without knowing the actual structure in design time - it must be general, generic.
This structure MUST NOT be linked to actual database records (like RecordSet).

Is there such a thing or I must make something like that manually?

Comment: did you ever search in Google ? hint : it's about Java.

Comment: Yes, I have searched but didn't found anything useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afaid that you can't find anything like this in the Android SDK. As far as I know, every data container Android offers out of the box needs you to know the structure of the data in design time. E.g. SQLite needs a schema, SharedPreferences only stores typed key-value pairs and you only have basic file storage besides these.

There might be some libary that offers what you're after, though I'm not aware of any.